# iOS header search path

Tags: ios, cordova, path, ffmpeg, linker

So I'm pretty new to iOS development and I'm a little confused by the header search paths. Here are the ones it's already including:

[image]

I presume some (if not all) of these are present because it's a cordova project.

In my file structure I've added a folder with the FFmpeg libraries (the FFmpeg folder is on the same level as classes within the app directory). I presume I want to include everything in the lib subfolder (they're all `.a` files) so my file structure is:

App Folder (Same level as the `.xcodeproj` file) > FFmpeg > FFmpeg-iOS > lib > `.a` files.

Could somebody suggest to me what linker I should use or how I somewhere I can look to find out?

Thanks.

---

I'm trying things like:

$(PROJECT_DIR)/AppFolder/FFmpeg/FFmpeg-iOS/include

and

$(SRCROOT)/AppFolder/FFmpeg/FFmpeg-iOS/include

and then I feel like I should be able to import it as:

`#import <libavcodec/avcodec.h>`

but it's just not finding it, I've tweaked the path a lot.